# `composer install` running on `hhvm` even if I require `php`

Tags: php, composer-php, hhvm

I have put

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5",
    "phpunit/phpunit": ">4,<6"
},
```

inside my composer.json file:

https://github.com/giorgiosironi/eris/blob/master/composer.json#L20

`composer install` however still accepts to be run on `hhvm`, as seen at:

https://travis-ci.org/giorgiosironi/eris/jobs/118241849

I thought requiring `php` meant I wanted a particular version of `php`, so `hhvm` was excluded. It seems instead that this choice means that *if* there is a `php` present, it must satisfy the version constraint, but if there is only `hhvm` it won't apply.

Is this what is happening? If so, how can I specify the package is incompatible with `hhvm`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [conflict](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#conflict) option to say that your package conflicts with HHVM. This would look like

```
"conflict": {
  "hhvm": "*"
}
```

which sets your package as conflicting with every version of HHVM.

Answer (score 0):

HHVM emits the `PHP_VERSION` constants. I'm fairly sure that composer simply uses those constants to figure out the version here.

My understanding is that `HHVM` has increased their `PHP_VERSION` as they obtained feature parity with the associated vanilla php version.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if `php` is in the required array is MUST be installed and be at least the version specified. As @Evert stated HHVM provides a php version when queried.

Check this out for hhvm dependency: https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#platform-packages